# Proxy auth with PhantomJS

Tags: python, selenium, authentication, scrapy, phantomjs

I'm trying to authenticate into proxy-server using PhantomJS with Python.
This is what I have

```
service_args = [
         '--proxy=http://us-ny.proxymesh.com:31280',
         '--proxy-type=http',

 ]

 authentication_token = "Basic " + base64.b64encode(b'username:pass')

 capa = DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS
 capa['phantomjs.page.customHeaders.Proxy-Authorization'] = authentication_token

 driver = webdriver.PhantomJS( desired_capabilities=capa, service_args=service_args)

 driver.get(request.url)
 body = driver.page_source
 print body
```

This only prints out

`<html><head></head><body></body></html>`

Just to clarify, this works when I add my IP to proxy servers - Authenticated IPs & Hostnames, but I need it to work without that

Comment: Bro I tried to configure proxies with Python Selenium and also with PhantomJS on Ubuntu and also on RedHat Linux ... spent 3 days but proxies did not work ...

Comment: oh boy, I really hope there is a way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution I have that works. I ended up needing to pass the credentials in both the service_args & as a proxy-auth header.

```
service_args = [
    "--ignore-ssl-errors=true",
    "--ssl-protocol=any",
    "--proxy={}".format(proxy),
    "--proxy-type=http",
]

caps = DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS

authentication_token = "Basic " + base64.b64encode(b'{}:{}'.format(username, password))

caps['phantomjs.page.customHeaders.Proxy-Authorization'] = authentication_token

self.driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(
        service_args=service_args,
        desired_capabilities=caps,
        executable_path="./phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs")
```

Where proxy's structure is defined as `http://username:password@domain:port`

I don't know why you have to repeat the credentials. I'd hazard a guess that the first auth-parameters aren't passed as a header to the proxy, so you need to do both manually.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use WebDriverWait to wait for the driver to load the website, once it's done you print the source code.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
service_args = [
         '--proxy=http://us-ny.proxymesh.com:31280',
         '--proxy-type=http',

 ]

 authentication_token = "Basic " + base64.b64encode(b'username:pass')

 capa = DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS
 capa['phantomjs.page.customHeaders.Proxy-Authorization'] = authentication_token

 driver = webdriver.PhantomJS( desired_capabilities=capa, service_args=service_args)

 driver.get(request.url)
 WebDriverWait(driver, *).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath(*)
 body = driver.page_source
 print body
```

Fill the * with seconds, xpath of the element you want to wait for.

Comment: Thanks, but still no results